# laravel doesn't login or auto logout?

Tags: authentication, laravel

I use ajax to do login

following is the laravel code. (never mind why not using Auth::attempt, because it's an old system I cannot migrate data now)

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');
$user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();

if(isset($user)) {
  if($user->pwd == strtoupper(md5($password))) {
    Auth::login($user);
    /****************************
    I print_r(Auth::User()), it did login successfully
    *****************************/
    echo 1;
  } 
}
```

and js code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'signin/submit',
  data: {"username": username, "password": password, "_token": _token},
  success: function(response) {
    switch (response) {
      case "1":
        // redirect to welcome page
        window.location.href = "welcome";
        break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

and the welcome page

```
class WelcomeController extends BaseController {
  public function index() {
    $this->layout->content = View::make('welcome');
  }
}
```

the welcome controller inherits BaseController, I put the auth filter in constructor of the BaseController

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

My problem is, when I redirect to welcome page after login successfully, it is always pushed back to the login page by the filter. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because just echo or json_encode cannot persist session

```
echo 1;  // or json_encode(1)
```

We must use Response::json, then the session tranfers from php to js

```
return Response::json(1);
```